# A problem with syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm writing an IDE for Python language in C++ and I have wrote a syntax highlighter for Python language syntax. but i have two problems with it:

1. my regular expression pattern for highkighting numbers is '\d+'. it highlights numers everywhere in code. for example it highlights '4' in 'Qt4' and i want to it doesn't highlight numbers in such cases.
2. my regular expression pattern for highkighting strings between two '"' is '\".*\"'. it works but with one problem. 
   it even highlights cases as '"some text1" some text2 "some text3"' and i want to it doesn't
   highlight 'some text2'.

what is solution for these two problems?

Comment: Highlighting syntax with regular expressions in 21st century? Nonsense! Python is a very simple language, so it really worth implementing a proper, semantics-aware parser instead.

Comment: @SK-logic or even better, use the Python source code to parse the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments it may not be appropriate to use regular expressions to parse a language.

Regarding your two questions:

1. You can circumvent this behaviour by using word boundaries: `\b\d+\b`
2. Make your expression non-greedy: `\".*?\"`

Note: As already mentioned those are only workarounds and may not be correct in any case.

Comment: I've tested pattern '\b\d+\b' but it causes pure digital string not be highlighted!